# Running Javascript onFocus - Changing DIV html text

Tags: javascript, onfocus

Currently I am trying to setup my contact form to give an error message when an invalid email is entered. When a blank or incorrect e-mail is submitted the page should do the following:

- Sign Up text changes to 'Retry'
- Red text appears within input field stating 'Address entered not valid'

When the user focuses on the input field, or presses 'retry'; all the form elements should go back to their original state. I have been able to get the text to change from red to black using the onFocus method. I attempted to create a small little javascript named reset, which I hoped to change the DIV text from 'Retry' back to 'Sign Up'.

I'm certain my issue is with the Javascript. Can someone point me in the right direction? :)

For code reference:
http://itsmontoya.com/work/playdeadcult/indextest.php

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Post your html, and the JavaScript you've tried to create so far.

Comment: So are you trying to reset the button label to "Sign Up" when the user focuses on the text input?

Comment: I posted the live code at the bottom of my post. I figured this would be sufficient so you could see the intended view.

Comment: @kavin.mansel - Exactly :). I was able to get everything to change back to the original except for the button text. I think it would be best to perform all these actions within a javascript. I setup reset() to be used for this purpose. I like the way Knix is going with it. For some reason, my implementation is incorrect. As you see, with this method, the text does not change back from red to black.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the commented out block of your reset() function what you need help with? If so, you can try the jQuery version of it since you have jQuery loaded anyway =)

The following is for your reset() function which changes text color to red:

```
$('#email').val('').css('color', '#FF0000').css('font-size', '18px');
```

The following is for your blur() function which changes text color to black. Attach this to your email input text box as well and you should be set:

```
$('#email').blur().css('color', '#000000');
```

Comment: You can then use this same concept on all the elements that you have to reset.  I would recommend using classes instead of doing this though.  It would be easier to manage and maintain.

Comment: Well I originally was trying to make reset change the style of the email ID, but I was running into weird issues. I decided to declare these styles within the onFocus. I can remove the commenting and update it to the method you suggested.

Comment: Ok so I updated the reset script and I changed the onFocus to run reset(). Now I lost the functionality of the text changing back from red to black. I'm sure I'm either calling it wrong or I did something incorrect when declaring the reset function. http://itsmontoya.com/work/playdeadcult/indextest.php is the live link for these changes :)

Comment: Hi Josh. You are currently using reset() for the onfocus() event which is currently changing the text to black => #000.  If you want the text to be red, you can simply change it to #FF0000 (red).  If the text is black by default or onblur, then you would have to attach the black font there.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is, with the html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="emailAddress">Sign up for the newsletter</label>
        <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="email" />
        <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var emailEntry = document.getElementById('emailAddress');
var button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
var defaultButtonText = button.innerHTML;

emailEntry.onblur = function(){
    var val = this.value;

    // the following IS NOT a valid test of email address validity
    // it's for demo purposes ONLY

    if (val.length < 5 && val.indexOf('@') == -1){
        button.innerHTML = 'retry';
        button.style.color = 'red';
    }
    else {
        button.innerHTML = defaultButtonText;
        button.style.color = 'black';
    }
};

button.onclick = function(){
    // prevent submission of the form if the email was found invalid
    // and the innerHTML was therefore set to 'retry'
    if (this.innerHTML == 'retry'){
        return false;
    }
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vmXhX/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function validate() {
    if($("#buttonDiv").html()== 'Retry')
    {
        // oops! They are trying to get back to where they were by 
        // re-clicking retry. Let's reset this thing
        reset()
        return false;
    }
    var emDiv = document.getElementById('email') // only look up once.
    if(emDiv) {
        // the space after the . should allow for 6 long
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,6})$/;
        var address = emDiv.value;
        // good form issue -- never use == false. use !
        if(!reg.test(address)) {
            emDiv.value = 'Address entered not valid';
            emDiv.style.color = '#bf4343';
            emDiv.style.fontSize = '12px';
            $("#buttonDiv").html( 'Retry' );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it appears as if this takes advantage of the reset JS I setup. I think something may be wrong with the way I wrote it though. When I try to run it on it's own, it doesn't perform the intended result :(.